# How to get input from user with placeholder?

Tags: rust, user-input

I'm currently writing a simple Notepad app in Rust. During the main loop, the user is asked to insert, delete, or change lines. When the user changes a line, I'd like to pre-fill the content of the line so that the user can edit a line easier.

Something like this (The underscore represents the terminal cursor. The user has not made any input after selecting the line):

```
Content:
1. Test
2. 123
Action(Change, Insert, Delete) --> C
Which line --> 2
--> 123_
```

I've found some crates that could help: Crossterm and Termion. Ncurses could help too, but I'd prefer not to use it.

Comment: So you're writing [`ex`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_(text_editor))? Why not use a "curses" library? It'll make it a lot easier to use, akin to something you'd expect to find in the 1980s instead of the paper-teletype era of the 1960s.

Comment: I think the problem you'll find here, very quickly, is that printing stuff out does not make it "inputtable", and that if you accept backspace without limitation, the screen will quickly get corrupted. Even a super stupid basic editor is going to need limits, like backspacing only to the start of the line, and dealing with lines wider than the terminal screen. You'll have to track what keys were hit, remove characters from the buffer, and append as typing occurs. Not going to be fun!

Comment: Or if you don't want a full TUI library, [`rustyline`](https://crates.io/crates/rustyline) has [`readline_with_initial`](https://docs.rs/rustyline/latest/rustyline/struct.Editor.html#method.readline_with_initial).

Comment: @Jmb That's exactly what I needed. Do you mind posting this as an answer, so I can mark this question as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use a full TUI crate like [`ratatui`](https://crates.io/crates/ratatui) or a lower-level "curses"-like terminal handling crate like [`termion`](https://crates.io/crates/termion), you can still use [`rustyline`](https://crates.io/crates/rustyline) for basic input with line editing. Specifically for editing a pre-filled line, you would use [`readline_with_initial`](https://docs.rs/rustyline/latest/rustyline/struct.Editor.html#method.readline_with_initial):

```
let mut rl = rustyline::DefaultEditor::new()?;
let line = rl.readline_with_initial ("-->", ("123", ""))?;
```